# Spyder crashing in new Anaconda environment

Tags: python-3.x, windows, spyder, anaconda3

In short, Spyder is crashing on my pc and I have no idea as to why.

In long, here are the steps of my process:

1. Launching Anaconda Prompt
2. conda create -n env_truc python=3.10
3. conda activate env_truc
4. conda install spyder
5. spyder
6. Spyder launches for 5 seconds then crashes.
7. When relaunching command spyder in Anaconda Prompt, it says Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\envs\env_truc\python.exe C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\envs\env_truc\Scripts\spyder-script.py '

Note that before launching spyder, python.exe can be found in C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\envs\env_truc\python.exe but not after it crashes. C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\envs\env_truc\Scripts\spyder-script.py is still here before and after launching spyder.
Note also that it doesn't crash when running spyder from base environment (which I don't know why either).

I uninstalled and reinstalled several times Anaconda with no success. I don't know why spyder randomly crashed at some point and on again because it was working perfectly well before.

Could you please help me?

Thank you very much!

Edit: creating an environment with python 3.9 doesn't seem to make spyder crash... Still no idea why python 3.10 crashes.